# Docker and VS Mac

Tags: docker, visual-studio-mac

Following the instructions on Docker's page I created a very simple Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
 FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
 WORKDIR /app

 # Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
 COPY *.csproj ./
 RUN dotnet restore

 # Copy everything else and build
 COPY . ./
 RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

 # Build runtime image
 FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dockertest.dll"]
```

This is literally a copy of the sample on Docker's [site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application) just changed the application name.

I used Visual Studio for Mac to create a very simple ASP.Net application (actually, just the default app with a tiny HTML file added in).

When I first ran `docker build -t dockertest .` the line with `dotnet publish` failed. I then ran the `dotnet publish` manually and got past that.

It now fails on the copy:

Step 9/10 : COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

```
 COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/1484306cebf1def83638270757e70a8cf874fb5a167f39e5bfaae92a47cc071c/merged/app/out: no such file or directory
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

So did you run `dotnet publish` inside the container or on the host machine? The Docker file is trying to run those commands inside the container, so running those on the host will not fix the issue.

Have you tried to right click your project and "Add Docker Support" to your app in VS for Mac? It should generate a docker file and then you can run/debug your app inside the container from within VS.